# 'int' does not uspport indexing

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to make a loop for a string that contains 16 numbers, idea is to multiply *2 all the pair digits, but while doing that, I get an error of a string. I tried several ways but not succeeding.

```
cardNumber = input("Enter a 16-digit card number:")
cardNumber = int(cardNumber.replace(" ",""))
#cardNumber = str(cardNumber)
print(cardNumber)
i = 0
for i in range(0, 16, 2):
  cardNumber[i] *= 2
  print(cardNumber)
```

Can you help me to understand this simple issue? I do not understand why is not allowing it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please share your input, the error you get, and the expected output

Comment: input: 1111 1111 1111 1111 / I expect: 2121212121212121  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Because you cast `cardNumber` to an integer, and as it says, you can't index integers

Comment: There is no way to say "give me the 3rd digit of 1234" or, at least, not with general indexing. You could ask for the 3rd character of "1234" (as a string, but it's not a string any more)

Comment: if I convert to string it says TypeError: 'str' does not support item assignment on line 11 in main.py, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert `cardnumber` to an integer, e.g. `4137894711755904`. Integers do not have a "digit position", thus `cardNumber[i]` cannot work. This indexing works on strings, but not on number types.

You could convert the string to a list of integers, e.g.

```
card_number= input("Enter a 16-digit card number:")
digits = list(map(int, list(card_number.replace(" ","")))) 
# Line above is short for [int(i) for i in list(card_number.replace(" ",""))]
```

Now indexing works as exected.
To get an integer back you can join the list and convert to int again, e.g.

```
number = int(''.join(map(str, digits)))
```

Answer (score 1):

the following maybe meet what you want :)

```
cardNumber = input("Enter a 16-digit card number:").replace(" ","")
numbers = [ int(x) for x in cardNumber ]
i = 0
for i in range(0, 16, 2):
  numbers[i] *= 2
  
print(numbers)

var = '' 
#iterate over the list elements
for element in numbers: 
    # converting integer to string and adding into variable
    var += str(element)
 
# converting back into integer and printing the final result
print(int(var))
```